# Opacity not working as background color for popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a popup that I created that works just fine, but for some reason I am having issues with the background-color opacity. On my page the script runs and I am not getting any errors. When the popup first comes up it shows the opacity, but then very quickly the color turns a bit darker and is a solid color rather than having any transparency. I created a fiddle, but cannot get it to perfectly replicate what is going on in my page. In my fiddle, it does not allow the popup to close, but on my page that is not the case.

https://jsfiddle.net/hvLtezza/

On my site it looks like this...

[image]

I have the almost exact same popup else where on this same page, with this as the jquery and I do not have any issues.

```
//Tech Help pop up script
    $('.admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.close_admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
     });
```

I cannot change my jquery in the jsfiddle I shared because it has a function in it that I need to get my page to work correctly.

Does anyone see why my page is not allowing the opacity to go through?

Comment: Well the problem with your fiddle is that your background overlay is a child of your popup. That's why it's covering it.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you’re having a style issue but I'm not able to reproduce with the code you provided. Please make sure your code demonstrates the issue you want solved.

Comment: More information needed.

Comment: What else would be helpful to add. I am not sure why the issue is not replicated in the fiddle as my page. I wasn't sure if it was my jquery code because the fact I have a pop up exactly the same on the page, just with a different jquery script and it works perfectly.

Comment: In order to help, we'll need to see the error as it occurs on your page. Either duplicate it in a fiddle or post a link to your website if it's not sensitive.